# Onclick does not fire ... possible javascript syntax issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an onclick to fire but it just won't, been trying for hours now.

Can anyone see any issues with the following code?

```
output += '<li><a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://www.google.com',{ showLocationBar: true });">link</a></li>';
```

I have the feeling it's something to do with the syntax somewhere.

Comment: The first thing you should do for any javascript error is to run it in Firefox and start up Firebug (and FireQuery if you're using jQuery).  Those will tell you the answer a lot faster than posting on StackOverflow will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the colour coding of your own post. Clearly you need to escape the single quotes inside the string.

```
output += '<li><a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(\'http://www.google.com\',{ showLocationBar: true });">link</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with quotes. Look at the error console I am sure it is yelling at you.

You need to escape the with a `\`

```
output += '<li><a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(\'http://www.google.com\',{ showLocationBar: true });">link</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `'`-delimited string within a `'`-delimited string. You need to escape the inner `'`:

```
output += '<li><a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(\'http://www.google.com\',{ showLocationBar: true });">link</a></li>';
```